# Failed to execute management command 'le on' (code: 17, error: Invalid Index)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am working on connecting my computer to a Parrot Mambo minidrone via Bluetooth through a Raspberry Pi and the `pyparrot` code library. I am trying to run the `findMinidrone.py` file in the `pyparrot` library and am receiving a `BTLEManagementError` when I run the file. I am using a Raspberry Pi 2 that is running the newest version of Raspbian Stretch.

I've already tried these solutions:

- https://github.com/amymcgovern/pyparrot/issues/30
- https://github.com/IanHarvey/bluepy/issues/190
- https://github.com/IanHarvey/bluepy/issues/218
- https://github.com/IanHarvey/bluepy/issues/313

This is the return statement when I ran `sudo python3 findMinidrone.py`:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/pyparrot/pyparrot/scripts $ sudo python3 findMinidrone.py   
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "findMinidrone.py", line 49, in <module>
    main()
  File "findMinidrone.py", line 30, in main
    device = scanner.scan(10.0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/bluepy.btle.py", line 852, in scan
    self.start(passive.passive)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/bluepy.btle.py", line 790, in start
    self._mgmtCmd("le on")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/bluepy.btle.py", line 312, in mgmtCmd
    raise BTLEManagemementError("Failed to execute management command '%%s'" % (cmd), rsp)
bluepy.btle.BTLEManagementError: Failed to execute management command 'le on' (code: 17, error: Invalid Index)
```

Comment: did you found ?